# How To insert item (record) on top in Recycler View in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created database and I am inserting record in that I am also selecting record from database and viewing record in recycler view. Now What I want to do is that I want to have new record on top of recycler view list. Here is small code of Recycler View...

rvstudent=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.r1);
rvstudent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

```
    RecyclerOfHomework adapter= new RecyclerOfHomework(list);
    rvstudent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Try sorting your list

Comment: Please consider breaking down your problems and elaborate more on each

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to implement this thing.
1> Add your new data at 0 indexes in the list and then set adapter in recycler view. and if you don't want to update recycler view every time then you can use another way.

2> Use the Local database to create date field names and sort them while fetching them.